# B2C Custom Policy Claims Transformation: Set outputclaim to stringCollection?

Tags: azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

Looking for a way to set outputclaim as a stringCollection based on a inputclaim which is either a stringCollection (group claims) or a boolean.

I am unable to find a TransformationMethod that fullfils my requirement.

Checked the following TransformationMethod and none has a outputclaim that supports stringCollection:

SetClaimIfBooleansMatch
SetClaimsIfRegexMatch
SetClaimsIfStringsMatch

Am I missing something or is there any workaround to this?

**UPDATE**

my need is to get the group claims from an IdP and set one or more roles based on the group membership(s).

the struggle is to set hooli.roles as a stringCollection to use as a list... none of the TransformationMethod support my usecase.

below is a 2-step process... tried a single ClaimsTransformation as well...

```xml
<ClaimType Id="groups">
  <DisplayName>Security groups</DisplayName>
  <DataType>stringCollection</DataType>
  <DefaultPartnerClaimTypes>
    <Protocol Name="SAML2" PartnerClaimType="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/claims/groups" />
  </DefaultPartnerClaimTypes>
</ClaimType>

<ClaimType Id="hooli.role.analyst">
  <DisplayName>Hooli Role - Analyst</DisplayName>
  <DataType>boolean</DataType>
</ClaimType>

<ClaimType Id="hooli.roles">
  <DisplayName>Hooli Roles</DisplayName>
  <DataType>string</DataType>
</ClaimType>

<!-- Step #1 -->
     <ClaimsTransformation Id="SethooliRole.Analyst" TransformationMethod="StringCollectionContains">
        <InputClaims>
          <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="groups" TransformationClaimType="inputClaim" />
        </InputClaims>
        <InputParameters>
          <InputParameter Id="item" DataType="string" Value="Analyst Group" />
          <InputParameter Id="ignoreCase" DataType="string" Value="true" />
        </InputParameters>
        <OutputClaims>
          <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="hooli.role.analyst" TransformationClaimType="outputClaim" />
        </OutputClaims>
      </ClaimsTransformation> 

<!-- Step #2 -->      
      <ClaimsTransformation Id="ishooliRole.Analyst" TransformationMethod="SetClaimIfBooleansMatch">
        <InputClaims>
          <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="hooli.role.analyst" TransformationClaimType="claimToMatch" />
        </InputClaims>
        <InputParameters>
          <InputParameter Id="matchTo" DataType="string" Value="true" />
          <InputParameter Id="outputClaimIfMatched" DataType="string" Value="Analyst" />
        </InputParameters>
        <OutputClaims>
          <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="hooli.roles" TransformationClaimType="outputClaim" />
        </OutputClaims>
      </ClaimsTransformation>
```

Comment: There are no natively supported claims transformations for this, but depending on the complexity of the requirements this may be possible. Please add examples and sample data of what you're trying to achieve. Note, it might be easiest for you to use a [Validation Technical Profile](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/validation-technical-profile) that calls to an external [REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/restful-technical-profile) to do the processing

Comment: added additional info to my original post... hope you can provide some guidance. thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need to output the string then a third claims transformation to add it to `hooli.roles`. I've added a sample of how this would look below

```xml
<ClaimType Id="groups">
  <DisplayName>Security groups</DisplayName>
  <DataType>stringCollection</DataType>
  <DefaultPartnerClaimTypes>
    <Protocol Name="SAML2" PartnerClaimType="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/claims/groups" />
  </DefaultPartnerClaimTypes>
</ClaimType>

<ClaimType Id="hooli.role.analyst">
  <DisplayName>Hooli Role - Analyst</DisplayName>
  <DataType>boolean</DataType>
</ClaimType>

<ClaimType Id="tmpRoleLookupOutput">
  <DisplayName>temp claim for holding role transformations</DisplayName>
  <DataType>string</DataType>
</ClaimType>

<ClaimType Id="hooli.roles">
  <DisplayName>Hooli Roles</DisplayName>
  <DataType>stringCollection</DataType>
</ClaimType>

<!-- Step #1 -->
<ClaimsTransformation Id="SethooliRole.Analyst" TransformationMethod="StringCollectionContains">
  <InputClaims>
    <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="groups" TransformationClaimType="inputClaim" />
  </InputClaims>
  <InputParameters>
    <InputParameter Id="item" DataType="string" Value="Analyst Group" />
    <InputParameter Id="ignoreCase" DataType="string" Value="true" />
  </InputParameters>
  <OutputClaims>
    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="hooli.role.analyst" TransformationClaimType="outputClaim" />
  </OutputClaims>
</ClaimsTransformation> 

<!-- Step #2 -->      
<ClaimsTransformation Id="ishooliRole.Analyst" TransformationMethod="SetClaimIfBooleansMatch">
  <InputClaims>
    <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="hooli.role.analyst" TransformationClaimType="claimToMatch" />
  </InputClaims>
  <InputParameters>
    <InputParameter Id="matchTo" DataType="string" Value="true" />
    <InputParameter Id="outputClaimIfMatched" DataType="string" Value="Analyst" />
  </InputParameters>
  <OutputClaims>
    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="tmpRoleLookupOutput" TransformationClaimType="outputClaim" />
  </OutputClaims>
</ClaimsTransformation>

<!-- Step #3 -->
<ClaimsTransformation Id="AddTo-hooli.roles-Collectionn" TransformationMethod="AddItemToStringCollection">
  <InputClaims>
    <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="tmpRoleLookupOutput" TransformationClaimType="item" />
    <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="hooli.roles" TransformationClaimType="collection" />
  </InputClaims>
  <OutputClaims>
    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="hooli.roles" TransformationClaimType="collection" />
  </OutputClaims>
</ClaimsTransformation>
```

Note, I haven't tested what happens if you try to add a null claim to a collection using `AddItemToStringCollection`. You may need to wrap the step 3 in a different technical profile with a precondition to avoid this scenario should it error.

Comment: your suggestion worked. thank you!